# .sort not working with Firefox

Tags: javascript

I wrote a Javascript app that I didn't think any modern browser would have any issue with, but when I tested it, it worked fine with Chrome, Safari, Opera, even IE… but not Firefox.

This is the sort in question:

```
var sorted = Object.keys(teams).sort(function(a, b) {
    return -(teams[a][sortBy] < teams[b][sortBy])
});
```

Here's a JSfiddle I made to demonstrate - http://jsfiddle.net/Aq6sc/1/

What that fiddle should do, is when you click on one of the categories, it should show you 3 "columns".  The team name, the category name, and the category value.  They should print sorted by category value ascending.  And it does in every browser except Firefox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comparison function should return a negative number if the left operand comes before the right one in the sort order, a positive number if the right operand comes first, and 0 if they are equal. Your function only returns -1 or 0. Use this:

```
var sorted = Object.keys(teams).sort(function(a, b) {
    var l = teams[a][sortBy], r = teams[b][sortBy];
    return (l < r) ? -1 : ((l > r) ? 1 : 0);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Aq6sc/4/

Here's a version that behaves exactly the same but might be considered a little more readable:

```
var sorted = Object.keys(teams).sort(function(a, b) {
    var l = teams[a][sortBy], r = teams[b][sortBy];

    if (l < r) { return -1; }
    if (l > r) { return 1; }
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: Yikes, that is complicated!  But it works!  Good job!

Comment: Weird thing is, on both firefox 20.0.1 and 26.0, your jsfiddle works fine for me.

Comment: @DanGoodspeed I've added a version that is longer but might be a little easier to understand.

Comment: Awesome @JLRishe, thanks.  Do you know if there is someway to make a variable to specify to sort ascending or descending?  Right now I'm just doing a binary check after the sort to see if it it should be descending, and if so, just do a sorted.reverse().  But maybe there's a better way?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed Could you provide a new fiddle with what you have so far?

Comment: Hmm… let's say I wanted RRI and OW to sort descending, I could do something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/dangoodspeed/Aq6sc/5/ .  In my real world example, the call to runSort has a second parameter whose value would be either "up" or "down", and that would determine the sort direction.

Comment: Here's how you can do this with the addition of the direction parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/Aq6sc/6/

Comment: Awesome.  I think I'm going to keep my way of doing it though, not because your way isn't good.  It's just that I'll never have more than a couple dozen objects in the array, so performance really isn't an issue, but being able to go back to the code down the road and understand exactly what I did and be able to comfortably edit it.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the sort compare function, you are using a `-` to reverse the result. If you use `!`, it should work fine.

```
var sorted = Object.keys(teams).sort(function(a, b) {
    return !(teams[a][sortBy] < teams[b][sortBy])
});
```

Or you can remove the not and just reverse the comparision

```
return (teams[a][sortBy] > teams[b][sortBy])
```

Comment: Both of these modifications cause the sorting to stop working in IE.

Comment: Changing the "-" to a "!" causes the sort to break for every browser.

Comment: Does ie still break if you add the missing semicolon?

return !(teams[a][sortBy] < teams[b][sortBy]);

Comment: @Noishe Yes, it breaks because the logic is wrong, not because it lacks a semicolon.